# Installing infinite scroll within iframe

Tags: jquery

I have tried to install a jscroll.js within the iframe. The following js plugin is the script that makes infinite scroll work at a very convenient way.

http://jscroll.com/

I have tried installing this plugin before on a regular page, so I thought it wouldn't be a difficult problem since doing the same thing again but this time it's on an iframe.

The website I'm currently working on is my personal website that works in sort of like a window user interface, which appears when you click on the button that reads '공지사항' on the bottom of the page.

The basic interface uses very simple addclass and removeclass jquery function, and when you click on the other menu, it jquery attrs to change the src of the iframe within the .window div that contains iframe.

I have first tried to implement this jscroll.js within the iframe document,but it gave me Cross Origin controls error.

So, then I again implemented the plugin inside the main page,not the page that gets loaded inside the iframe.

But now I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

The thing I'm trying to achieve here is that, the infinite scroll to be worked inside the iframe that appears when you click on the button that reads '공지사항' on the bottom of the page.

Can anyone tell me what I have missed, and how to fix?

Here is the script:

```
<script>
 /* infinite scroll */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#window_frame').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<center><img src="layouts/window/ajax-loader.gif"        alt="Loading" /> Loading...</center>',
    padding: 0,
    contentSelector: '.board_list',
    autoTriggerUntil: 3,
    nextSelector:'.next_button'
}); });
```

And this is my website [link](http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/).

Comment: P.S. if i change the target from #window_frame to .window, it still doesn't work

Comment: and currently i have changed it to .board_content yet still no function.